# Why react doesn't see .env

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `.env` which has `REACT_APP_API_URL = http://localhost:5000/`. I use it in this code snippet

```
import axios from "axios";

const host = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
});

const authHost = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
});
```

When I try to output `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);` then the value is displayed undefined, why is that? The `.env` file is located in the directory where all client files are present

Comment: 'The .env file is located in the directory where all client files are' it should be the project's root dir. And if you edited the .env file after running the app then you must stop and start again, the .env file is loaded once the app started

Comment: @Andrey Smith, did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?

```
npm install dotenv
```

In your config file add:

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first install dotenv: npm i dotenv
after that import this to file: const dotenv = require("dotenv")
and config dot env: dotenv.config()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `.gitignore` file, sometimes the `create-react-app` adds `.env` file to the .gitignore entry. Maybe that's the reason.